# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure 01

Tags: android, mysql, android-studio, jdbc

Никак не могу подключится к MySQL с помощью JDBC c емулятора Nox.

Пересмотрел другие ответы, ничего не помогает. С компьютера подключение проходит успешно, с емулятора ошибка:

```
01-16 18:27:49.949 2869-2882/com.example.rostyslav.cactus W/System.err: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
01-16 18:27:49.949 2869-2882/com.example.rostyslav.cactus W/System.err: The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
01-16 18:27:49.959 2869-2882/com.example.rostyslav.cactus W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
01-16 18:27:49.959 2869-2882/com.example.rostyslav.cactus W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
01-16 18:27:49.959 2869-2882/com.example.rostyslav.cactus W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
01-16 18:27:49.959 2869-2882/com.example.rostyslav.cactus W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:989)
01-16 18:27:49.959 2869-2882/com.example.rostyslav.cactus W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:341)
01-16 18:27:49.959 2869-2882/com.example.rostyslav.cactus W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2189)
01-16 18:27:49.969 2869-2882/com.example.rostyslav.cactus W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2222)
01-16 18:27:49.969 2869-2882/com.example.rostyslav.cactus W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2017)
01-16 18:27:49.969 2869-2882/com.example.rostyslav.cactus W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:779)
01-16 18:27:49.969 2869-2882/com.example.rostyslav.cactus W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
01-16 18:27:49.969 2869-2882/com.example.rostyslav.cactus W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
01-16 18:27:49.969 2869-2882/com.example.rostyslav.cactus W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
01-16 18:27:49.969 2869-2882/com.example.rostyslav.cactus W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
01-16 18:27:49.979 2869-2882/com.example.rostyslav.cactus W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:389)
01-16 18:27:49.979 2869-2882/com.example.rostyslav.cactus W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:330)
01-16 18:27:49.979 2869-2882/com.example.rostyslav.cactus W/System.err:     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:179)
01-16 18:27:49.979 2869-2882/com.example.rostyslav.cactus W/System.err:     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:213)
01-16 18:27:49.979 2869-2882/com.example.rostyslav.cactus W/System.err:     at com.example.rostyslav.cactus.database.Database.createConnection(Database.java:31)
01-16 18:27:49.979 2869-2882/com.example.rostyslav.cactus W/System.err:     at com.example.rostyslav.cactus.DataBase.doInBackground(CourseListActivity.java:74)
01-16 18:27:49.979 2869-2882/com.example.rostyslav.cactus W/System.err:     at com.example.rostyslav.cactus.DataBase.doInBackground(CourseListActivity.java:62)
01-16 18:27:49.989 2869-2882/com.example.rostyslav.cactus W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
01-16 18:27:49.989 2869-2882/com.example.rostyslav.cactus W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
01-16 18:27:49.989 2869-2882/com.example.rostyslav.cactus W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
01-16 18:27:49.989 2869-2882/com.example.rostyslav.cactus W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
01-16 18:27:49.989 2869-2882/com.example.rostyslav.cactus W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
01-16 18:27:49.989 2869-2882/com.example.rostyslav.cactus W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
01-16 18:27:49.989 2869-2882/com.example.rostyslav.cactus W/System.err: Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.1.5 (port 3306): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
01-16 18:27:49.999 2869-2882/com.example.rostyslav.cactus W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)
01-16 18:27:49.999 2869-2882/com.example.rostyslav.cactus W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
01-16 18:27:49.999 2869-2882/com.example.rostyslav.cactus W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
01-16 18:27:49.999 2869-2882/com.example.rostyslav.cactus W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:843)
01-16 18:27:49.999 2869-2882/com.example.rostyslav.cactus W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:211)
01-16 18:27:49.999 2869-2882/com.example.rostyslav.cactus W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:300)
01-16 18:27:50.009 2869-2882/com.example.rostyslav.cactus W/System.err:     ... 21 more
01-16 18:27:50.009 2869-2882/com.example.rostyslav.cactus W/System.err: Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
01-16 18:27:50.019 2869-2882/com.example.rostyslav.cactus W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
01-16 18:27:50.019 2869-2882/com.example.rostyslav.cactus W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:85)
01-16 18:27:50.019 2869-2882/com.example.rostyslav.cactus W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
01-16 18:27:50.019 2869-2882/com.example.rostyslav.cactus W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
01-16 18:27:50.019 2869-2882/com.example.rostyslav.cactus W/System.err:     ... 26 more
```

Вот сам код:

```
public void createConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        url = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.5:3306/mydb";
        uname = "root";
        pass = "";
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, uname, pass);
    }
```

Comment: `The driver has not received any packets from the server.` проверяйте настройки сети/брендмауэров. У Вас пакеты не ходят до сервера или обратно

Comment: Брендмауэр отключен

Comment: Ищите проблему в сети. В коде ее нет